# react-hook-forms & Netlify. Not passing form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify, react-hook-form

I have just spent the last couple of hours, trying to get the validation and netlify to work well together...validation works, and the form gets submitted ok. However, it doesnt seem to be sending any of the form data.

My form component is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'

function encode(data) {
    return Object.keys(data)
        .map(
            key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key])
        )
        .join('&')
}

const ContactForm = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm({
        mode: 'onChange',
    })
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({})
    const handleChange = e =>
        setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

    const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const form = e.target
        fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: encode({
                'form-name': 'react-validation-form',
                body: data,
            }),
        })
            .then(response => {
                reset()
                navigate(form.getAttribute('action'))
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center">
            <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                name="react-validation-form"
                method="POST"
                data-netlify="true"
                data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
                className="w-full sm:w-2/3"
                action="/"
                id="contactForm"
            >
                <label className="block text-xs uppercase font-sans font-bold mb-2 text-gray-700">
                    Full Name:
                </label>
                <input
                    name="fullName"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Your name please"
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                    className="mb-4 shadow appearance-none border rounded-lg w-full py-4 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-wider font-sans text-sm focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                />
                {errors.fullName && (
                    <div
                        class="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative text-xs font-sans mb-4"
                        role="alert"
                    >
                        <strong class="font-bold mr-2">Holy smokes!</strong>
                        <span class="block sm:inline">
                            Something seriously bad happened.
                        </span>
                    </div>
                )}

                <label className="block text-xs uppercase font-sans font-bold mb-2 text-gray-700">
                    Email
                </label>
                <input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="I wont spam you promise"
                    ref={register({
                        required: true,
                        pattern: {
                            value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                        },
                    })}
                    className="mb-4 shadow appearance-none border rounded-lg w-full py-4 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-wider font-sans text-sm focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                />
                {errors.email && (
                    <div
                        class="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative text-xs font-sans mb-4"
                        role="alert"
                    >
                        <strong className="font-bold mr-2">Holy smokes!</strong>
                        <span className="block sm:inline">
                            Please enter a valid email address.
                        </span>
                    </div>
                )}

                <label className="block text-xs uppercase font-sans font-bold mb-2 text-gray-700">
                    Your Message
                </label>
                <textarea
                    name="message"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Talk to me..."
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                    rows="4"
                    className="mb-4 shadow appearance-none border rounded-lg w-full py-4 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-wider font-sans text-sm focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                />
                {errors.message && (
                    <div
                        class="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative text-xs font-sans mb-4"
                        role="alert"
                    >
                        <strong className="font-bold mr-2">WHAAAAT!!</strong>
                        <span className="block sm:inline">
                            You got to tell me something!
                        </span>
                    </div>
                )}

                <button
                    type="sumbit"
                    className="w-full bg-gray-900 text-gray-200 font-extrabold rounded-lg tracking-wider font-sans text-sm uppercase py-4  hover:bg-blue-800"
                >
                    send message
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ContactForm
```

This is what is getting printed to the console:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "https://mrpbennett.com/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: "https://mrpbennett.com/"
__proto__: Response
```

`body: ReadableStream` and `bodyUsed: false` gives me the indication that something is not right here. Any ideas how I can resolve this, and get the form to present the form data in the response.

Live working example is here: https://mrpbennett.com/contact

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Data is an object already, if you put it inside a nested objet (body in this case) the map function of the encode method returns "object&object" because is an object.

You need to eliminate the body property inside the fetch function and spread the data objet in order to be iterable for the encode function.

change this:

```
fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: encode({
            'form-name': 'react-validation-form',
            body: data,
        }),
    })
```

for this

```
fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: encode({
            'form-name': 'react-validation-form',
            ...data,
        }),
```