# Forms with React are recognized but submits are not captured

Tags: reactjs, next.js, netlify, netlify-form

I've been using Netlify forms for awhile and love them. This is the first time that I have used them in a react app however, and I am having some trouble getting them to work. I followed the official guide and my form is being recognized and showing in my dashboard, but submitting does nothing. No errors are logged to the  console. I have tried fiddling around with attributes etc, but just cant seem to get it to capture the submit, and not sure where to start looking.

Here is my site: eddie-traylor.netlify.app/
Here is my github repo: github.com/naughty-cat-team/eddie-traylor

Here is my index.html code which I have included under the body section:

```
<form name="contact" netlify netlify-honeypot="bot-field" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="tel" name="phone" />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  </form>
```

Here is my contact form component:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Contact = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => window.location.replace("/thankyou");

  return (
    <div className="px-6 mx-auto md:px-8 max-w-[1110px]">
      <div className="bg-white p-6 xl:px-10">
        <div className="hero-bg md:flex md:items-start xl:mt-10">
          <div className="pt-[50px] px-6 text-white md:px-10 md:basis-1/2">
            <h2>CONTACT</h2>
            <p className="mt-4">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse nam, beatae quas dolorum cum temporibus? Veniam ullam quibusdam nam! Sint delectus fugit eveniet
              blanditiis quas ratione animi vero cum.
            </p>
          </div>

          <form method="post" name="contact" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="contact px-6 pb-[70px] md:px-10 md:basis-1/2 md:pt-[50px]">
            <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
            <div className="mb-[50px] space-y-[14px]">
              <div className="relative w-full">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  {...register("name", {
                    required: "Required",
                  })}
                  placeholder="Name"
                  className={`${errors.name ? "border-red placeholder:text-red/50" : ""}`}
                />
                {errors.name && <p className="absolute bottom-5 text-[12px] leading-[18px] tracking-[.08px] text-red right-4 md:right-6 italic">{errors.name.message}</p>}
              </div>
              <div className="relative">
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  {...register("email", {
                    required: "Required",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$/,
                      message: "Invalid",
                    },
                  })}
                  placeholder="Email Address"
                  className={`${errors.email ? "border-red placeholder:text-red/50" : ""}`}
                />
                {errors.email && <p className="absolute bottom-5 text-[12px] leading-[18px] tracking-[.08px] text-red right-4 md:right-6 italic">{errors.email.message}</p>}
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" {...register("phone")} placeholder="Phone" />
              </div>
              <div className="relative">
                <textarea
                  type="text"
                  name="message"
                  cols="30"
                  rows="4"
                  {...register("message", {
                    required: "Required",
                  })}
                  placeholder="Your Message"
                  className={`${errors.message ? "border-red placeholder:text-red/50" : ""}`}
                ></textarea>
                {errors.message && <p className="absolute bottom-5 text-[12px] leading-[18px] tracking-[.08px] text-red right-4 md:right-6 italic">{errors.message.message}</p>}
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn text-center text-white w-[170px] h-auto md:w-auto">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Thanks so much for any help or guidance!

Brenden

Comment: Probably you know and not related to `netlify-form`. But in the case you do not know about form support in Next 14. Check this out: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a duplicate question, though the answers I received helped me narrow down my search. I basically used this answer and formatted it for my needs.

[react-hook-forms & Netlify. Not passing form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662511/react-hook-forms-netlify-not-passing-form-data)

Thanks everyone for pointing me down the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Update below code. Directly add errors and add console log for errors

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    errors
  } = useForm();
```

On submit there may be some error on field and because of that it wont submit the form. Check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried using your code, and commenting out all the related chunks in the component and still now luck! Thank you loads, no errors, but no submissions either. Any other thoughts? Not sure if I have to use Ajax or something, but I haven't been able to get that to work either unfortunately.

Comment: Hey, was able to finally get it working with ajax! The trick was getting it to work with react-hook-form. I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662511/react-hook-forms-netlify-not-passing-form-data and adapted it to my use case. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Remove the method from the `<form method="post"/>` tag, this tell html to make a post request is to the `url set in the action attribute` which is neither provided nor necessary in this case.
2. for this hidden tag `<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />` replcae it with this `<input type="hidden" {...register("form_name")} />`

then update your `useForm` with this

```
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    form_name: "contact",
  },
});
```

3. remove the name attribute from the `<form />` this is also not necessary.
4. remove the name attributes from the `<input/>`'s and the `<textarea/>`. React hook forms register function add's them as props to the tags you spread it on based on the name you pass as the first parameter. `register("<field_name>")`. This should resolve your issue, if they don't, remove the `onSubmit` from the `<form/>` and pass it to the `<button />` as an `onClick`. e.g.

```
 <form>
  <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} 
  className="">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I was able to resolve my issue with ajax, but I use the forms often so I will try this method on the next site. Always good to have options! I will update once I have had a chance to try.